# How to fix this mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following  MYSQL query:

```
if(isset($_GET["keywords"])) {
  $keywords = $db->escape_string($_GET["keywords"]);
  $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE scriptures LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR books LIKE '%{$keywords}%'");

  ?>

  <div class='result-count'>
    Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> results.
  </div>
  <?php

  if($query->num_rows) {
    while($r = $query->fetch_object()) {
      ?>
        <div class='result'>
          <?php
            $scriptures_link = $r->scriptures_link;
            $books_link = $r->books_link;

          echo "<a href='$scriptures_link'> Hi </a> <br>";
          echo "<a href='$books_link'> Bye </a> <br>";
          ?>
        </div>
      <?php
    }
  }

}
```

I have two separate categories: `scriptures` and `books`. The LIKE statement targets both of these groups. So, if one row of information has info for both of these items. Therefore, if one item matches the LIKE statement, but the other does not, both items show up in the search results. How do I separate up the query, to only do one at a time?

Comment: Have you tried using DISTINCT?  SELECT DISTINCT *

Comment: @JohnEasley Yes, and it's not working...

Comment: Do you mean you don't want rows returned that match both sets of keywords?  Can you give some sample data, and the expected results?

Comment: @SilicaGel Unless both sets of data meet it, I only want one data to display the information. Let's say `scriptures` is Happy and `books` is Sad. If I search `Happy`, then books will also show. They both show because they are both part of the same row. How can I keep both data on the same row, but only return one if only one meets it?

Comment: Are you actually getting the same row back twice, or once, but trying to determine which column matched the keywords?

Comment: @SilicaGel I'm getting the row once, but each row has both sets of data included. I have no way of knowing if the data came from `scriptures` or `books`. So, I have no way of determining which column matched the keywords...

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a Case statement.

```
SELECT *,
  CASE
    WHEN scriptures LIKE '%{$keywords}%' THEN scriptures_link
    WHEN books LIKE '%{$keywords}%' THEN books_link
  END as the_link
FROM data WHERE scriptures LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR books LIKE '%{$keywords}%'"
```

Then echo out $r->the_link

Let me know if that works. (I haven't tested the query, but I think its right.)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include your original where statement, i've added it.

Comment: This may not give you the desired results if the keywords matched both. Did you want 2 links if it matches both?  Let me know how the above query works before answering this question, and we can make revisions.

Comment: Awesome job, but yes, if the keywords match both, I want both links to display. Otherwise, I want only one to display.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss something in this line..

```
echo "<a href='$scriptures_link'> Hi </a> <br>";
      echo "<a href='$books_link'> Bye </a> <br>";
```

Try this one..

```
echo "<a href='".$scriptures_link."'> Hi </a> <br>";
      echo "<a href='".$books_link."'> Bye </a> <br>";
```

Hope this help... :D